# Maven+Selenium 2: How to run tests with one single browser open

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to run some tests, seven to be specific, I've created my xml file and all and it works correctly, my test file has a package which has the seven tests in it, so the thing is, when the xml file is executed it opens a new browser window for each test (in case you were wondering, I do have the driver quit and close functions, they are at the @afterTest annotation) and I don't want that, what I need is just to get one browser open at all times, e.g. after finishing test one, close that browser because for the second test a second browser is open, what I'll like to get is to close each browser after each test is finished, is it a way to achieve that?

Here is my pom file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.enterprise.automation</groupId>
<artifactId>enterpriseAutomation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>barcoAutomation</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- added -->
    <suiteFile>src/test/resources/barcoColor.xml</suiteFile>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
        <!-- <classifier>jdk17</classifier> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/myTestsFile.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

EDIT: the reason i don't want the seven browsers opened is because we are testing a SPA which has a lot of javascript and it consumes a bit too much pc resources, so if more than one browser are opened the computer performance drops

I also saw the "-1", if you could tell how to improve the question details I'll appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: Upvoting to undo the downvote. Question looks quality to me. By `one browser open at all times`, do you mean having all 7 tests run in one session without closing the browser in between? Please describe the behavior you are getting and what you want it to do exactly.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I'll like to run each test in a separated browser, e.g., after finishing test one, close that browser because for the second test a second browser is open, what I'll like to get is to close each browser after each test is finished, hope this help

Comment: That does clear it up. Consider editing your question: that seems opposite to what your text indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `@AfterTest` and `@BeforeTest` use `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite`

Create a BaseTest class containing @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite.

```
public class BaseTest{
    static WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void start() {
        driver = new FFDriver();
        driver.get(url);
    }


    @AfterSuite
    public void end() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Create Test classes.

```
public class Test1{
    static WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        driver = BaseTest.driver;
        //code goes here
    }
}


public class Test2{
    static WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        driver = BaseTest.driver;
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

Modify testNG xml file as follows.

```
<suite name="Regression Testing" parallel="classes">
    <test verbose="2" name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="BaseTest"/>
            <class name="Test1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test verbose="2" name="Test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="Test2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The @BeforeSuite is run first followed by Test1, Test2 and @AfterSuite. Driver instance is obtained in each Test class by setting driver as static in BaseTest.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: will do and I'll let you know

Comment: that worked perfectly! just one more question before closing this question, what does the **verbose="2"** means or where can I find more information about it? Thanks

Comment: It is used for specifying the level of testNG execution detail to be displayed in the console. http://seleniumone-by-arun.blogspot.in/2013/05/158-understanding-usage-of-verbose.html

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately our company policies have a restriction on personal blogs, but I'll take a look at it at home, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, if you say you want "to get is to close each browser after each test is finished", you need to use @AfterMethod and @BeforeMethod.  This would ensure that after every @Test runs, the browser gets closed.

With @AfterTest, this would happen just once - note Test in @AfterTest maps to `<test>` in the testng xml and does not map to @Test in your code.

@AfterSuite would just close your browser once in the entire execution, which would mean if you wanted a clean session on each @Test, that won't happen.

If you do not want a clean session, then @Before/@AfterSuite would work as well.

Comment: thanks Niharika, with your answer I learned something new today, I give you an upvote but I'm new at this still